# UIView animation curve not working easeinout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimation-curve

I am stumped by a very simple task, I want a UIView animation to do ease in / ease out but it is always linear despite using the correct animationOption.

Here is the code which by all accounts should work, it's set in a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning class but I have the same issue in a previous custom segue class;

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void) {

        self.dimView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.imageView.frame = self.destinationRect;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.dimView removeFromSuperview];

        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];

     }];
```

However, a spring animation with the following code works although I'd rather not do this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.7f initialSpringVelocity:2.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void) {

        self.dimView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.imageView.frame = self.destinationRect;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.dimView removeFromSuperview];

        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];

     }];
```

I'm getting the same behaviour on the simulator and on an iPad2 test device.
Am I doing something wrong?
Are there issues with animating either frame or alpha values?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this instead.-

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop)];

self.dimView.alpha = 1.0;
self.imageView.frame = self.destinationRect;

[UIView commitAnimations];

- (void) animationDidStop {
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.dimView removeFromSuperview];
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ssantos. At first I thought it did the trick but my eyes were fooling me. Still definitely linear. Very strange and annoying.

Comment: Mmh weird indeed, may the distance be too small to notice the difference? I'd try a 'large' animation with different `animationCurves` just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

[self transition:left]; //Call as required

```
enum animationFrom {
    top,
    bottom,
    left,
    right
};

- (void)transition:(NSUInteger)index {
    CATransition *tr=[CATransition  animation];
    tr.duration=0.45;
    tr.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    tr.type=kCATransitionPush;
    tr.delegate=self;
    switch (index) {
        case top:
            tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromBottom;
            break;
        case bottom:
            tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromTop;
            break;
        case left:
            tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
            break;
        case right:
            tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromLeft;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:tr forKey:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default animation curve option is `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`, so you don't need to specify this one. It is `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` that you have to be explicit about.

Are you sure your animation curve is linear? Try animating two views side be side, with animation duration set to a few seconds.